# How can I install a 32bit python on 64 bit Ubuntu

Tags: 64-bit, python, 32-bit

I am using Ubuntu 10.10 (`Linux pc07 2.6.35-27-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 22 20:25:46 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux`) and the default python package (Python 2.6.6).

I would like to install `python-psyco` to improve the performance of one of my scripts, but only `python-psyco-doc` is available for 64 bit. 
I tried a virtual machine, but the the performance boost is much less on the virtual machine than on a "real" installed 32-bit Ubuntu.

So my question is: How can I install a 32Bit Python with psyco on my 64Bit Ubuntu machine?

edit: I've found [this article](http://blog.devork.be/2009/02/compiling-32-bit-python-on-amd64.html) and made this:

- Download "Python 2.7.1 bzipped source tarball" from http://python.org/download/
- Go in the directory where you decompressed "Python 2.7.1"
- `OPT=-m32 LDFLAGS=-m32 ./configure --prefix=/opt/pym32`
- `make`

But I got this error:

```
gcc -pthread -m32 -Xlinker -export-dynamic -o python \
            Modules/python.o \
            libpython2.7.a -lpthread -ldl  -lutil   -lm  
libpython2.7.a(posixmodule.o): In function `posix_tmpnam':
/home/moose/Downloads/Python-2.7.1/./Modules/posixmodule.c:7346: warning: the use of `tmpnam_r' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'
libpython2.7.a(posixmodule.o): In function `posix_tempnam':
/home/moose/Downloads/Python-2.7.1/./Modules/posixmodule.c:7301: warning: the use of `tempnam' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'
Segmentation fault
make: *** [sharedmods] Fehler 139
```

edit2: Now I've found http://indefinitestudies.org/2010/02/08/how-to-build-32-bit-python-on-ubuntu-9-10-x86_64/ and it seems like this worked:

- `cd Python-2.7.1`
- `CC="gcc -m32" LDFLAGS="-L/lib32 -L/usr/lib32 \
  -L`pwd`/lib32 -Wl,-rpath,/lib32 -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib32" \
  ./configure --prefix=/opt/pym32`
- `make`
- `sudo make install`

But installing psyco didn't work:

- Download the lastest snapshot: http://psyco.sourceforge.net/download.html
- Extract it and go into the folder
- python setup.py install

This error appeared:

```
PROCESSOR = 'ivm'
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'psyco._psyco' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DALL_STATIC=1 -Ic/ivm -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c c/psyco.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/c/psyco.o
In file included from c/psyco.c:1:
c/psyco.h:9: fatal error: Python.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Installing the package `python-dev` solved the problem, but I still could not use psyco. Now I've installed a 32Bit Ubuntu System.

Comment: why not just compile for 64bit, since python is an interpreted language?

Comment: The compilation fails for me. Output of `make` says ```Could not build the ssl module!
Python requires a OpenSSL 1.1.1 or newer```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To run 32 bit applications on a 64 bit Ubuntu system, you will need `ia32-libs`.
From a terminal, validate if you have this using

```
dpkg -l ia32-libs
```

If you've installed it, the output should looks like:

```
ii   ia32-libs ...
```

If it looks like `un  ia32-libs`, you need to install it using:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't working in Ubutu 14.04

vharron@tifa:~/ll/googd/build/x86l$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0

E: Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. I am still not sure how to download / compile python 32bit.

Answer (score 4):

I finally got this to work by installing a 32-bit schroot'ed environment.  Follow the directions here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DebootstrapChroot

I used the following configuration file for my schroot (`/etc/schroot/chroot.d/natty32.conf`):

```
[natty32]
description=Ubuntu 11 for i386
directory=/srv/chroot/natty32
personality=linux32
root-users=myloginname
type=directory
users=myloginname
```

Once installed, start the schroot session:

```
schroot -c natty32 -u root
```

Then install python2.6 with apt-get, install pip using it ( http://guide.python-distribute.org/installation.html ), then pip install psyco, numpy, &c.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work with the following:

```
for pkg in build-essential:i386 gdb:i386 lcov:i386 pkg-config:i386 libbz2-dev:i386 libffi-dev:i386 libgdbm-dev:i386 libgdbm-compat-dev:i386 liblzma-dev:i386 libncurses5-dev:i386 libreadline6-dev:i386 libsqlite3-dev:i386 libssl-dev:i386 lzma:i386 lzma-dev:i386 tk-dev:i386 uuid-dev:i386 zlib1g-dev:i386
do
apt-get -y install $pkg
done
```

then running Martin Thoma's script (I needed --enable-shared in order to produce libpython*.so files):

```
CC="gcc -m32" LDFLAGS="-L/lib32 -L/usr/lib32 \
-Lpwd/lib32 -Wl,-rpath,/lib32 -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib32" \
./configure --prefix=/opt/pym32 --enable-shared
make
sudo make install
```