# Ubuntu 16.04 - Having both 32bit and 64bit python

Tags: python, 64-bit, 32-bit

I'm trying to install [python-pin](https://github.com/blankwall/Python_Pin). This tool uses Pin (an Intel instrumentation tool) which is 32bit. When I try to run python-pin, I get:

```
E: Unable to load /home/censored/Documents/tools/Python_Pin/obj-intel64/Python_Pin.so: dlopen failed: library "libpython2.7.so.1.0" not found
```

I do have libpython2.7.so.1.0, located at:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0
```

But it's in 64 bit while the library requiring it is 32 bit. After doing a fair bit of research, I've found these questions that were similar to mine:

[How can I install a 32bit python on 64 bit Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29253/how-can-i-install-a-32bit-python-on-64-bit-ubuntu?rq=1)

This one is for Ubuntu 10.10 and the solution doesn't appear to work for me.

These one were more general:

[How do you run a 32-bit program on a 64-bit version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359156/how-do-you-run-a-32-bit-program-on-a-64-bit-version-of-ubuntu)

[How to run 32-bit app in Ubuntu 64-bit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454253/how-to-run-32-bit-app-in-ubuntu-64-bit)

After having read these, I installed the 32bit version of python-dev with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-dev:i386
```

The installation was successful, but I can't find the 32bit version of libpython2.7.so.1.0 anywhere and I'm still not able to launch python-pin.

EDIT:

I've manually compiled 32bit python this way:

```
$ CC="gcc -m32" LDFLAGS="-L/lib32 -L/usr/lib32 \
-Lpwd/lib32 -Wl,-rpath,/lib32 -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib32" ./configure --prefix=/opt/pym32 --enable-shared
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

And now I finally have a 32bit libpython2.7.so.1.0 file in my Python folder. Still, when I do:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=/home/censored/Documents/tools/Python-2.7.13/libpython2.7.so.1.0 bin/python-pin Python_Pin/examples/ins_count.py /bin/ls
```

I get these errors:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/censored/Documents/tools/Python-2.7.13/libpython2.7.so.1.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
```

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7988772/1959808